# Is it possible to promote the controlling expression of _Generic to array type, if it's a pointer?

Tags: c, generics, macros

I need to promote the controlling expression (i.e.: the first, main argument) of `_Generic` to array type **if** it's a pointer, and leave it unchanged for a non-pointer type. I know the opposite effect: the decay of an array type into an "equivalent" pointer type, however, it is not what I want…

In other words, the following should work:

```
#define PROMOTE_MACRO(x) _Generic(something(x),\
    int[8] : 1, default: 0)
int *ptr, normal;
printf("%d, %d\n", PROMOTE_MACRO(ptr), PROMOTE_MACRO(normal));
// outputs: 1, 0
```

The size of the array doesn't matter (it could be dropped, however `_Generic` requires a complete type name…). All I need is a compile safe way of promoting a (and **only**) pointer to its equivalent array type of some size. Is it possible?

Comment: No. Just add a case in the generic for the pointer type: `_Generic((x), int [8] : 1, int * : 1, default : 0)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: However, I would like to have a macro for a *generic* type… Basically, I want to this way solve the currently considered (Google says…) impossible `IS_POINTER(x)` macro, that should evaluate to true if `x` is a pointer type…

Comment: How would answering the question you asked, promoting a pointer to an array in `_Generic`, assist you in testing whether something is either “any kind of pointer“ or “any kind of array”? I do not see the relationship between promoting a pointer to an array and testing for generic pointers/arrays.

Comment: **If** the promotion would be **optional**, **only** for pointer types, it would open the long enough searched (by me, at least) way of differentiating between pointer and non pointer in the `_Generic()` statements… By simply matching a… say (not fully correct, will not compile for a non-pointer type): `typeof(*x)[1] : 1, default: 0`.

Comment: Hmm, so your intent is that `_Generic(something(x), typeof(*x) [1] : 1, default : 0)` would, given a pointer `x`, promote it to an array, say of 1 element, and then match `typeof(*x) [1]`? As you note, this will not compile for a non-pointer type. Suppose it did. Then you could do `_Generic(x, typeof(*x) *: 1, default: 0)`. In other words, you do not need promotion-to-array to make this work; you need `*x` to compile. In any case, there is no way to cause promotion to arrays. Even arrays do not remain arrays here; C 2018 6.5.1.1 2 says the first argument undergoes array-to-pointer conversion.